# Modificar dos clases con un formulario

Tags: django

Me dispuse a diseñar una app para un torneo de tenis.

Tengo una clase: *Jugador* y otra clase: *Desafio*
donde los jugadores se desafian entre sí.

Actualmente estoy queriendo permitir a un jugador que finalizó un desafío poder cargar los resultados de su partido a la base de datos. Al realizar esto quiero que no solo modifique los atributos del desafío, sino que también le sume una unidad a "partidos jugados" y "partidos perdidos" o "ganados" a la instancia del jugador.

Mis Models:

```
class Jugador(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False,blank=False)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    posicion = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    pj = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pg = models.IntegerField(default=0)  
    pp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    desafiado = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural =  'jugadores'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


class Desafio(models.Model):
    atacante = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    defensor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    at1set = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    de1set = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    at2set = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    de2set = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    attb = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    detb = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    pendiente = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    fecha = models.DateField(default=date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Desafio entre {self.atacante} y {self.defensor}'
```

Mis views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import Jugador, Desafio
from .forms import JugadorForm, DesafioForm
# Libs especiales
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import Http404

# Create your views here.

#main site



def index(request):
    jugadores = Jugador.objects.order_by('posicion')    
    context = {'jugadores': jugadores, }
    return render(request,'escalerilla/index.html', context)
    
    

@login_required
def nuevo_jugador(request):
    form = JugadorForm(request.POST or None) 
    tot_jugadores = len(Jugador.objects.all())
    if request.method =='POST':         
        if form.is_valid(): 
              
            obj = form.save(commit = False) 
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.posicion = tot_jugadores + 1
            obj.save() 
            form = JugadorForm() 
            messages.success(request, "Successfully created") 
          
    return render(request, 'escalerilla/nuevo.html', {'form':form}) 

def ficha_jugador(request,jug_id):
    jugador = Jugador.objects.get(id=jug_id)
    mijugador = Jugador.objects.get(user=request.user)
    context = {'jugador':jugador, 'mijugador':mijugador}

    return render(request,'escalerilla/ficha.html',context)

def mi_ficha(request):
    mij = Jugador.objects.get(user=request.user)
    des = Desafio.objects.filter(atacante=mij.nombre,pendiente=True)
    context = {'mij':mij, 'des':des}

    return render(request,'escalerilla/mi_ficha.html',context)

@login_required    
def desafio(request,jug_id):
    #contexto del desafio
    atacante = Jugador.objects.get(user=request.user)
    defensor = Jugador.objects.get(id=jug_id) 
    
    
    if atacante == defensor:
        mensaje = f'No podes desafiarte a ti mismo'
        context = {'mensaje':mensaje}
        
        
        
    elif defensor.desafiado == False :
        atacante.desafiado = True
        defensor.desafiado = True
        atacante.save()
        defensor.save()
        #Crear el desafio
        desafio = Desafio()
        desafio.atacante = atacante.nombre
        desafio.defensor = defensor.nombre
        desafio.save()
       
        context = {'defensor':defensor, 'desafio':desafio}
        
        
    else:
        mensaje = f'El jugador {defensor.nombre} tiene un desafio pendiente.'
        context = {'mensaje':mensaje}
        

      
    return render(request, 'escalerilla/desafio.html', context)
 
    
@login_required
def pends(request):
    des = Desafio.objects.filter(pendiente=True)
    context = {'des':des}
          
    return render(request,'escalerilla/pends.html',context)

@login_required
def ipends(request,jug_id):
    mij=Jugador.objects.get(id=jug_id)
    des = Desafio.objects.filter(Q(atacante=mij.nombre,pendiente=False)|Q(defensor=mij.nombre,pendiente=False))
    pendientes = Desafio.objects.filter(pendiente=True)
    context = {'des':des, 'pendiente':pendientes,'mij':mij}
          
    return render(request,'escalerilla/ipends.html',context)

@login_required
def update_desafio(request, des_id):
    """editar un desafio pendiente"""
    desafio= Desafio.objects.get(id=des_id)
    mij=Jugador.objects.get(user=request.user)
    
    #chequeo 
    if desafio.atacante != mij.nombre and desafio.defensor != mij.nombre:
        return render(request,'escalerilla/deny.html')

    elif request.method != ('POST'):
        #visualizar la info actual del desafio
        form = DesafioForm(instance=desafio)
    else:
        # POST agregar informacion del desafio
        form = DesafioForm(instance=desafio, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        
        
            obj = form.save(commit = False) 
            obj.pendiente = False
            obj.save() 
            

            #Identificar ganador y perdedor
            get_ganador=definir_ganador(obj)
            get_perdedor=definir_perdedor(obj,get_ganador)
            
            #retrieve la instancia 
            perdedor = Jugador.objects.update(nombre=get_perdedor)
            ganador = Jugador.objects.get(nombre=get_ganador)
            
            #actualizar datos del Jugador
            ganador.pg += 1
            ganador.pj += 1
            perdedor.pp += 1
            perdedor.pj += 1
            ganador.save()
            perdedor.save()
           

            return redirect('escalerilla:mi_ficha')
    
    context = {'desafio': desafio, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'escalerilla/update.html', context)

def definir_ganador(obj):
    
    if obj.detb != obj.attb:
        if obj.detb > obj.attb:
            return obj.defensor
        else:
            return obj.atacante
    elif obj.at1set > obj.de1set:
        return obj.atacante
    else:
        return obj.defensor

def definir_perdedor(obj,ganador):
    if ganador == obj.defensor:
        return obj.atacante
    else:
        return obj.defensor

def eliminar_desafio(request,des_id):
    desafio = Desafio.objects.get(id=des_id)
    at = desafio.atacante
    de = desafio.defensor
    get_juga = Jugador.objects.get(nombre=at)
    get_jugd = Jugador.objects.get(nombre=de)
    get_juga.desafiado = False
    get_jugd.desafiado = False
    get_juga.save()
    get_jugd.save()
    desafio.delete()
    return render(request,'escalerilla/deleted.html')
```

Aparentemente el código que me está trayendo problemas es este:

```py
#Identificar ganador y perdedor
get_ganador=definir_ganador(obj)
get_perdedor=definir_perdedor(obj,get_ganador)

#retrieve la instancia 
perdedor = Jugador.objects.update(nombre=get_perdedor)
ganador = Jugador.objects.get(nombre=get_ganador)

#actualizar datos del Jugador
ganador.pg += 1
ganador.pj += 1
perdedor.pp += 1
perdedor.pj += 1
ganador.save()
perdedor.save()
```

¿Alguna idea?

Consigo actualizar los datos* del desafío pero estoy teniendo un error:

**edicion**
Agrego el traceback completo, muchas gracias. Tambien hice algunas modificaciones en views asi que agregue todos los views

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/update/19/

Django Version: 4.0.4
Python Version: 3.10.4
Installed Applications:
['users',
 'escalerilla',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (UNIQUE constraint failed: escalerilla_jugador.nombre) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\Documents\Programming\Python\tennis2\escalerilla\views.py", line 135, in update_desafio
    perdedor = Jugador.objects.update(nombre=get_perdedor)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 865, in update
    rows = query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1783, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1361, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Matias Etcheverry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /update/19/
Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: escalerilla_jugador.nombre
```

Gracias, espero novedades

Comment: Por favor comparte el log completo del error, no solo el ultimo mensaje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema parece ser cuando se recupera la instancia del jugador que perdió, en lugar de hacer un **.get** se hace un **.update**:

```
#retrieve la instancia 
perdedor = Jugador.objects.update(nombre=get_perdedor)
```

Esto intenta actualizar el valor del nombre de todos los jugadores con el nombre del perdedor. Por ello la violación a la condición de unicidad:

> Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: escalerilla_jugador.nombre.

Considero que lo se intentaba, como indica el comentario, era recuperar la instancia del jugador identificado con el nombre proporcionado, que sería algo como esto:

```
#retrieve la instancia 
perdedor = Jugador.objects.get(nombre=get_perdedor)
```

Comment: Entiendo, voy a cambiar el nombre de la variable y ver si resuelve.

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto! Muchas gracias @Rigoberto Ramirez Cruz!
Creo que Visual Studio Code autocompleto con un metodo que no era el intencionado. La idea mia era clara, se suponia que era un get de la base de datos.

Muchas gracias una vez mas